# Need to draw to surface used by MediaRecorder

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-mediarecorder

I need to record a video that just contains one single frame: an image specified by the user (it can be of any length, but it will only have the same static image). So, I figured I could use the new MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE and just draw to the Surface being used by the recorder. I initialize the recorder properly, and I can even call MediaRecorder.getSurface() without an exception (something that is apparently tricky).

My problem is somewhat embarrassing: I don't know what to do with the surface returned. I need to draw to it somehow, but all examples I can find involve drawing to a SurfaceView. Is this surface the same surface used by MediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay()? How do I draw something to it?

Answer (score 2):

In theory you can use [`Surface#lockCanvas()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface.html#lockCanvas(android.graphics.Rect)) to get a Canvas to draw on if you want to render in software.  There used to be [problems with this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61194) on some platforms; not sure if that has been fixed.

The other option is to create an EGLSurface from the Surface and render onto it with OpenGL ES.  You can find examples of this, with some code to manage all of the EGL setup, in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika).

The GLES recording examples uses MediaCodec rather than MediaRecorder, but the idea is the same, and it should be much simpler with MediaRecorder.

Comment: I just tried that: after recording was started I called lockCavas(), drew a line on the canvas, then called unlockAndPostCanvas(). However, when I stopped the recording I got a RuntimeException, which according to the documentation means no valid data was received for recording. I did not encounter the issue of incorrect color shifting like in the link you posted. Any ideas?

Comment: Color channel reversal is one possible outcome; outright failure is another. Sounds like you'll need to go the GLES route. (It's possible to use software rendering to create an off-screen Bitmap, upload the Bitmap as a texture with `glTexImage2D()`, and render that... so you don't need to convert all of the rendering to GLES commands.) If you start with the code in Grafika, and just `glClear()` and the scissor rect to draw colored rectangles on the screen, it should be possible to test things out without doing more than dip your toes into GLES.

Comment: it's possible to use MediaRecorder instead of MediaCodec with that Grafika example, but there is problem when MediaRecorder prepared with audio source https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63467704/mediarecorder-surface-input-with-opengl-issue-if-audio-recording-is-enabled So it works only ok if you record only video using mediarecording (without audio)

Comment: @fadden can help me with MediaRecorder. Why there is a problem when recording with Audio? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63467704/mediarecorder-surface-input-with-opengl-issue-if-audio-recording-is-enabled