# MediaRecorder Surface Input with OpenGL - issue if audio recording is enabled

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, android-mediarecorder

I want to use `MediaRecorder` for recording videos instead of `MediaCodec`, because it's very easy to use as we know.

I also want to use OpenGL to process frames while recording

Then I use example code from Grafika's ContinuousCaptureActivity sample to init EGL rendering context, create `cameraTexture` and pass it to Camera2 API as `Surface` https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java#L392

and create EGLSurface `encodeSurface` from our `recorderSurface` https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java#L418

and so on (processing frames as in Grafika sample, everything the same as in the example code Grafika code)

Then when I start recording (`MediaRecorder.start()`), it records video ok if audio source wasn't set

But if audio recording is also enabled

```
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
...
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
```

Then final video has large duration (length) and it's not really playable. So MediaRecorder audio encoder ruins everything when using Surface as input and GLES for adding and processing frames

I have no idea how to fix it.

Here's my code to process frames (based on Grafika sample, it's almost the same):

```
class GLCameraFramesRender(
    private val width: Int,
    private val height: Int,
    private val callback: Callback,
    recorderSurface: Surface,
    eglCore: EglCore
) : OnFrameAvailableListener {
    private val fullFrameBlit: FullFrameRect
    private val textureId: Int
    private val encoderSurface: WindowSurface
    private val tmpMatrix = FloatArray(16)
    private val cameraTexture: SurfaceTexture
    val cameraSurface: Surface

    init {
        encoderSurface = WindowSurface(eglCore, recorderSurface, true)
        encoderSurface.makeCurrent()

        fullFrameBlit = FullFrameRect(Texture2dProgram(Texture2dProgram.ProgramType.TEXTURE_EXT))

        textureId = fullFrameBlit.createTextureObject()

        cameraTexture = SurfaceTexture(textureId)
        cameraSurface = Surface(cameraTexture)
        cameraTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this)
    }

    fun release() {
        cameraTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(null)
        cameraTexture.release()
        cameraSurface.release()
        fullFrameBlit.release(false)
        eglCore.release()
    }

    override fun onFrameAvailable(surfaceTexture: SurfaceTexture) {
        if (callback.isRecording()) {
            drawFrame()
        } else {
            cameraTexture.updateTexImage()
        }
    }

    private fun drawFrame() {
        cameraTexture.updateTexImage()

        cameraTexture.getTransformMatrix(tmpMatrix)


        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)

        fullFrameBlit.drawFrame(textureId, tmpMatrix)

        encoderSurface.setPresentationTime(cameraTexture.timestamp)

        encoderSurface.swapBuffers()
       
    }

    interface Callback {
        fun isRecording(): Boolean
    }
}
```

Comment: p.s. with audio source it records ok on emulator, but problem with the real device (Samsung S8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very likely your timestamps aren't in the same timebase. The media recording system generally wants timestamps in the [uptimeMillis](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock#uptimeMillis()) timebase, but many camera devices produce data in the [elapsedRealtime](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock#elapsedRealtime()) timebase.  One counts time when the device is in deep sleep, and the other doesn't; the longer it's been since you rebooted your device, the bigger the discrepancy becomes.

It wouldn't matter until you add in the audio, since MediaRecorder's internal audio timestamps will be in uptimeMillis, while the camera frame timestamps will come in as elapsedRealtime. A discrepancy of more than a few fractions of a second would probably be noticeable as a bad A/V sync; a few minutes or more will just mess everything up.

When the camera talks to the media recording stack directly, it adjusts timestamps automatically; since you've placed the GPU in the middle, that doesn't happen (since the camera doesn't know that's where your frames are going eventually).

You can check if the camera is using elapsedRealtime as the timebase via [SENSOR_INFO_TIMESTAMP_SOURCE](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#sensor_info_timestamp_source). But in any case, you have a few choices:

1. If the camera uses TIMESTAMP_SOURCE_REALTIME, measure the difference between the two timestamp at the start of recording, and adjust the timestamps you feed into setPresentationTime accordingly (`delta = elapsedRealtime - uptimeMillis; timestamp = timestamp - delta;`)
2. Just use `uptimeMillis() * 1000000` as the time for setPresentationTime.  This may cause too much A/V skew, but it's easy to try.

Comment: Thanks for such detailed answer! I checked that Android Emulator returns `TIMESTAMP_SOURCE_UNKNOWN` and real device returns `TIMESTAMP_SOURCE_REALTIME`. I'll try to fix it for real devices (for emulator it works ok) with your suggested solutions and will response if it helped.

Comment: I've tried second solution and it works fine. But you say it still may cause A/V too much skew and it's better to use first solution? If using first solution should I define `delta = elapsedRealtime - uptimeMillis;` before `mediaRecorder.start()` or after?

Comment: I tried first solution like this `val timestampDelta = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` before `mediaRecorder.start()` and then `setPresentationTime(cameraTexture.timestamp - callback.getTimestampDelta())` but it didn't fix the problem. So for now only second solution works for me. I also thought mb you meant not `cameraTexture.timestamp` but `System.currentTimeMillis()` or `Instant.now().epochSecond` but also didn't work. Or I totally didn't understand first soltuion :)

Comment: Note that some of those methods return milliseconds, and others use nanoseconds - you may need to multiply / divide by 1,000,000 in a few places; sorry I didn't include the conversion factors in my option #1.  You can calculate the delta at any point your app is visible - the CPU isn't going to go to sleep while your app is running, generally.